# EmberJS multiple inverses of the same model type

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two data model

```
// users
export default DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr(),
    workspaces: DS.hasMany('workspace', { async: true })
});

// workspaces
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  owner: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  contributors: DS.hasMany('user'),
});
```

I expect this logic:

1) user.workspaces contains all workspaces that is owns + all can contribute to.

2) workspace.contributors => should get all contributors

3) workspace.owner => should get single owner.

Ember wouldn't work as it is defined currently and requires explicit inverse which I'm struggling to do.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible with relations, look here what problem it will lead to http://stackoverflow.com/q/31992024/2948109

Comment: You can remove workspaces from user and use store.filter to get all user's workspaces http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can work you just need to fix up your data model a bit.

```
// user
export default DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr(),
    workspacesOwning: DS.hasMany('workspace', { async: true, inverse: 'owner' }),
    workspacesContributing: DS.hasMany('workspace', { async: true, inverse: 'contributors'}),
    workspaces : Ember.computed.union('workspacesOwning', 'workspacesContributing')
});

// workspace
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  owner: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  contributors: DS.hasMany('user')
});
```

and then:

```
//This would now work
1) user.workspaces contains all workspaces that is owns + all can contribute to.

//Will now work
2) workspace.contributors => should get all contributors

//Will now work
3) workspace.owner => should get single owner.
```

You might want a join table to prevent the many-to-many between workspacesContributing/contributors but that is up to you.